# Lasker (?) on strategy and tactics

Tags: strategy, tactics, quotations, lasker, reference-request

Many years ago I read (in a Russian book) a saying

> Strategy is creating true values; tactics is refuting the false ones.

which the book attributed to Emmanuel Lasker.

Does anybody know where Lasker (if it was him indeed) say that?

PS: I wish I remember what book was that.

Comment: There is a longer version of the above at https://www.azquotes.com/author/23916-Emanuel_Lasker which is attributed to Lasker. Unfortunately it doesn't give a reference. Similarly at https://www.inspiringquotes.us/author/4769-emanuel-lasker/about-values

Comment: Is that reference from Valeri Beim's book?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you meant this one:

> "By positional play a master tries to prove and exploit true values,
> whereas by combinations he seeks to refute false values".

https://www.quotemaster.org/qd83c54f436b2ade86c4d1e5b217b40a4

Most likely published in Lasker's Chess Manual (which is a great book btw).